# Supervisord keeps repeating a process with an exit of zero.

Tags: docker, supervisord

I am working on having supervisord send a curl request upon start. however, despite my best efforts, I set auto restart to false, it keeps running the script.

```
[program:slack-client]
priority=99
autorestart=false
command=bash -c 'SOME BASH COMMAND'
```

The error that keeps repeating is

```
INFO exited: slack-client (exit status 0; not expected)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced with similar behavior of `rsyslog`. This workaround helped me (but I'm not sure if that's exactly your case):

```
[program:rsyslog]
command = rsyslogd -n -c3
startsecs = 5
stopwaitsecs = 5
```

Comment: New to docker, have this same issue, but I'm not sure in which config file to put this code.

Comment: ^ Nevermind, I found it in supervisord.conf, as documented here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/